# Custom shapes for different screen sizes in android

Tags: android, custom-component

I have Custom view which draws a series of rectangle shapes within the view. 
I have extended the View and overriden the onDraw method.

This is contructor(adding just the important part)

```
 public CustomDrawableView(Context mContext , AttributeSet attr)
    {
        super(mContext,attr);

        //setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight)
        Log.e("CustomDrableView", "widht"+attr.getAttributeName(5));
        Log.e("CustomDrableView", "widht2"+attr.getAttributeValue(5));



        mColors = new int[] {
            //color codes
            };


        mColors_state_init = new int[]
                {
                    //color codes
                };

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        mPaint2 = new Paint(mPaint);
        mPaint2.setAlpha(64);

        float[] radii = {15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15};
        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(radii, null, null));


       // mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        ShapeDrawable prev = mDrawable;
        mDrawables = new ShapeDrawable[15];

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            mDrawables[i] = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(radii, null, null));
        }
}
```

this is onDraw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {       
     mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
      for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        mDrawables[i].getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawables[i].setDither(true);
        mDrawables[i].setBounds(x, y + (i *20), x+width, y+height+(i*20));
      }


    for(int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++)
    {
         ColorFilter filter = null;

         if (mColors[i] == 0) {
                    filter = null;
                } else {
                    filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(mColors_test[i],
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);


        }


             mDrawables[i].setColorFilter(filter);
             mDrawables[i].draw(canvas);
    }
```

The width and height values have to change with different screen sizes. How can I achieve that?

I am specifying a static width and height for the view in the xml. Should I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you should avoid setting static width and height in xml, let them be wrap_content. And then, instead of doing like this

```
 float[] radii = {15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15};
```

find equivalent value for 15 according to screenSize. To achieve that you should get screen sizes. Once you got screenSizes, you can proportion size. It could be something like this:

```
 int calculatedValue = screenWidth * 15 / 320;    // I assume 320 as a default screen width here
 float[] radii = {calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue, calculatedValue}
```

And in case, if you don't know how to get screen sizes... Here's a snip:

```
 public void GetDimensions() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
}
```